# Как передать переменную из одной функции в другую в vkbottle?

Tags: python, vkbottle

Бот написан на библиотеке vkbottle. Хочу реализовать нормальную автооплату, но не получается реализовать проверку платежа, так как id платежа я получаю в другой функции.
Подскажите, как можно получить переменную IDE из функции "sfsg"?

```py
@bot.on.private_message(text='Сoглaceн')
async def sfsg(message: Message):
    IDE = random.randint(1, 99999)
    amount = 1
    lifetime = 15
    bill = p2p.bill(bill_id=IDE, amount=amount, lifetime=lifetime)
    await message.answer(f'Отлично! Для оплаты платежа вам необходимо указать код своего заказа в комментарии\n\nСсылка на оплату: {bill.pay_url}')
    await message.answer("Как произведёте оплату - нажмите *Проверить оплату*")
 
@bot.on.private_message(text='Проверить оплату')
async def adfusa(message: Message):
    await message.answer(IDE)
```

Answer (score 3):

Для того, что бы передать переменную из одной "функции" в другой, нужно её сохранить где-то глобально. И желательно это делать отдельно для каждого пользователя.

VKBottle предоставляет готовый функционал в виде [state-dispenser](https://vkbottle.readthedocs.io/ru/latest/high-level/handling/state-dispenser/)'ов. Они позволяют сохранять различные состояния для каждого пользователя, а так же сохранять произвольные данные (payload).

Решение будет выглядеть примерно так:

```py
from vkbottle import BaseStateGroup
from vkbottle.bot import Message, Bot

bot = Bot("token")


class MyStates(BaseStateGroup):
    IDE_STATE = 0
    ...


@bot.on.private_message(text='Сoглaceн')
async def sfsg(message:Message):
    IDE = random.randint(1,99999)
    await bot.state_dispenser.set(message.peer_id, MyStates.IDE_STATE, IDE=IDE)
    amount = 1
    ...


@bot.on.private_message(text='Проверить оплату')
async def adfusa(message:Message):
    IDE = message.state_peer.payload.get("IDE")
    await message.answer(IDE)
```